# How to retrieve all custom Page using sfdx?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcedx

Would like to ask if how to retrieve all custom pages from org using SFDX. I've been searching through the internet and haven't seen anything. In retrieving Apex Classes i use, `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass` is there anything similar to this but instead of Apex Classes, it would custom pages (Visualforce page) that i will be retrieving.

Answer (score 10):

The metadata type for Visualforce pages is [`ApexPage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_pages.htm). In general, it's the name of the Metadata API entity that you'll use with these commands, as well as in building a `package.xml` manifest file.

To retrieve all Visualforce pages, you use [`force:source:retrieve`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#!):

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexPage
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks david! And sorry for the typo. Already edited it.